# Katoolin has killed my system. Help removing it or at least recover files from my encrypted drive

Tags: boot, encryption, data-recovery, katoolin

I didn't do enough reading before installing this thing and now my system will not boot. It worked for a while (though my system was getting weird errors) but today I tried to boot, entered my password on the splash screen, then got sent to a flashing black screen.

I am currently running ubuntu from a cd right now.

I would really like to try to recover my system and remove all traces of katoolin, but I'm not sure how to do that.

At the very least I need to move my files from my HDD to an external drive if I need to do a clean install. The issue here is there are tons of folders, and I have no idea where any of my files are. I've randomly come across a few videos, but I had tons more stuff. How would I find the stuff I had in the major sections such as "Pictures" "Videos" "Documents" "Downloads" "Desktop" etc. Also, where could I find my Firefox bookmarks backup file?

Thanks for any help you guys can give. If you need any more info I can provide it.

Comment: I used the file manager to navigate to my hdd and /home/username and I am told I don't have permissions to open it. I ran terminal as root and inside are two files: Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop" and "README.txt" which says:
THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.
From the graphical desktop, click on:
"Access Your Private Data"
or
From the command line, run:
ecryptfs-mount-private
Would running this command allow me to access my files?

Comment: *"Katoolin has killed my system"* - That's a known bug.

Comment: Any advice? I'm following this guide now: http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/ but when I get to the part saying to run ecryptfs-recover-private I get two errors. "Find: '/run/user/999/gvfs': permission denied" and "find: File system loop detected; '/sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl' is part of the same file system loop as '/says/kernel/debug'." I'm not a super skilled Linux user so any help is appreciated.